# Way to monitor user installed applications in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-service

I'm developing an application to monitor third party application. I know how to get the list of running applications but the thing is, I can't figure out how to record information about all the running applications. What I want to record is the processor usage, Memory usage and Data usage of each an every running application. is it practical to use a DB to store the recorded application details. And the main thing is to get the usage data when I select a running application. the questions that I have is,

How to get the PID of a running application.
How to get the above details of a running application such as the processor and memory usage.

Please help me with this and if any one have source code or, a tutorial on achieving this, please e kind enough to comment!

thank you.

Comment: Try this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo.html Just get all running apps and u will also find the pid. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can periodically poll the system for installed apps.

sample code. android-sdk-linux/samples/android-15/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/Grid1.java

```
private void loadApps() {
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
    mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

    mApps = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
}
```